# Encontrar campos en un array con mongodb y golang

Tags: mongodb, go

Desde la consola puedo tranquilamente acceder a todos los valores que cumplan, por ejemplo:
userrtid: "5f93de9ad43f940b8ea9ff33"

esta instruccion utilizo en la consola de mongo:

```
db.getCollection('tweet').find({"retweet.userrtid":"5faa1d3837e1d221e7fb8f57"})
```

pero en golang me duvuelve siempre null

asi es como se muestra la coleccion

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f9cbfc44cbeb545d7af05e9"),
        "fecha" : ISODate("2020-10-31T01:37:08.063Z"),
        "userid" : "5f93de9ad43f940b8ea9ff33",
        "mensaje" : "A",
        "retweet" : [ 
            {
                "userrtid" : "5f93de9ad43f940b8ea9ff33",
                "fecha" : ISODate("2020-11-12T05:20:52.381Z")
            }, 
            {
                "userrtid" : "5f93de9ad43f940b8ea9ff33",
                "fecha" : ISODate("2020-11-12T05:21:22.487Z")
            }
        ],
        "like" : [ 
            {
                "userlikeid" : "5f93de9ad43f940b8ea9ff33",
                "fecha" : ISODate("2020-11-12T04:01:23.632Z")
            }
        ]
    }
```

en golang ejecuto esto

```
package bd

import (
    "context"
    "time"

    "github.com/martinmolina1988/twitter/models"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

/*LeoUsuariosConRT Lee los usuarios registrados en el sistema, si se recibe "R" en quienes
  trae solo los que se relacionan conmigo */
func LeoUsuariosConRT(ID string, page int64) ([]*models.DevuelvoTweets, bool) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 15*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    db := MongoCN.Database("twitter")
    col := db.Collection("tweet")

    var results []*models.DevuelvoTweets

    registro := bson.M{"userrtid": ID}
    cur, err := col.Find(ctx, bson.M{"retweet": registro})
    if err != nil {
        return results, false
    }

    for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {

        var registro models.DevuelvoTweets
        err := cur.Decode(&registro)
        if err != nil {
            return results, false
        }
        results = append(results, &registro)
    }
    return results, true

}
```

Ya no se que mas buscar, algo estare haciendo mal?
Parece algo tan sencillo pero no me deja avanzar

tengo que agregar texto por que me aparece "Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles." y no me deja postear

Comment: El problema lo tienes porque lo que guardas en `userrtid`es un `string` y no un `ObjectId`. Haz que la inserccion sea con `ObjectId` y prueba tu codigo. Ya nos confirmas.